# Parse get all the objects from a pointer column

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I want to get all the objects in a pointer column from a query. I have a object class named A that contains a pointer column to object B. (Only 1 object) I have a query for A and I want to get all the B objects from that query. So I'm trying to do something like this...

```
var queryA = PFQuery(classname: "A");
queryA.whereKey("level", equalTo: 1);

var queryB = PFQuery(classname: "B);// not sure if this is necessary
//here I couldn't find anything, this should be something like
//get objects from queryA's "objectB" column
//After merging the column key with queryB (assuming I can)
queryB.whereKey("games", lessThan: 5); //I add constraints
```

When I try to use queryB.whereKey("key", matchesKey: "objectB", inQuery: queryA) it doesn't work because the "objectB" key points to the B objects not a key in it. Do you guys have any ideas? (Any answer is greatly appreciated. I can understand Objective-C as well as Swift)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `includeKey()` method. It will get the related data for the pointer column.

```
var queryA = PFQuery(classname: "A");
queryA.whereKey("level", equalTo: 1);
query.includeKey("columnName");
```

The second query (`queryB`) is not necessary.